# Unable to pass the pre req for Openshift Origin Installation On CentOS 7

Tags: centos, openshift, openshift-origin

I am trying to install openshift origin on a three-node cluster (master, infra and compute). Ansible prereq is failing and I wanna understand why.

The command I using: -

> ansible-playbook
>   /usr/share/ansible/openshift-ansible/playbooks/prerequisites.yml
>   --extra-vars "deployment_type=origin ansible_ssh_user=origin ansible_ssh_pass=**********

/etc/ansible/hosts

```
[OSEv3:children]
masters
infra
compute.openshift.local
[OSEv3:vars]
# admin user created in previous section
ansible_ssh_user=origin
ansible_become=true
openshift_deployment_type=origin

# use HTPasswd for authentication
openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider'}]
# define default sub-domain for Master node
openshift_master_default_subdomain=master.openshift.local
# allow unencrypted connection within cluster
openshift_docker_insecure_registries=172.30.0.0/16

[masters]
master.openshift.local openshift_schedulable=true containerized=false

[etcd]
master.openshift.local

[nodes]
# defined values for [openshift_node_group_name] in the file below
# [/usr/share/ansible/openshift-ansible/roles/openshift_facts/defaults/main.yml]
# ctrl.srv.world openshift_node_group_name='node-config-master-infra'
# node01.srv.world openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'
# node02.srv.world openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'

# if you'd like to separate Master node feature and Infra node feature, set like follows
master.openshift.local openshift_node_group_name='node-config-master'
infra.openshift.local openshift_node_group_name='node-config-infra'
compute.openshift.local openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'
```

`fatal: [master.openshift.local]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to master.openshift.local closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "KeyError('ansible_os_family',)\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/origin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567193370.23-159849689337768/AnsiballZ_openshift_facts.py\", line 114, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/home/origin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567193370.23-159849689337768/AnsiballZ_openshift_facts.py\", line 106, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/home/origin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567193370.23-159849689337768/AnsiballZ_openshift_facts.py\", line 49, in invoke_module\r\n    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_openshift_facts_payload_REiGHs/__main__.py\", line 1270, in <module>\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_openshift_facts_payload_REiGHs/__main__.py\", line 1257, in main\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_openshift_facts_payload_REiGHs/__main__.py\", line 1010, in __init__\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_openshift_facts_payload_REiGHs/__main__.py\", line 1026, in generate_facts\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_openshift_facts_payload_REiGHs/__main__.py\", line 1204, in init_local_facts\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_openshift_facts_payload_REiGHs/__main__.py\", line 751, in save_local_facts\r\n__main__.OpenShiftFactsFileWriteError: Could not create fact file: /etc/ansible/facts.d/openshift.fact, error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/ansible/facts.d/openshift.fact'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
... [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/ansible/facts.d/openshift.fact'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

Above error messages are meaning `/etc/ansible/facts.d/openshift.fact` can not create on the nodes using `origin` user.
Could you verify whether `origin` user can escalate privileges as `root` on all the nodes ?

e.g.> For example, check whether you can take `root` permission using `sudo`.

```
origin@hostname ~$ sudo -i
root@hostname ~#
```